# Android makefile include dynamic library runtime error

Tags: java, android, makefile, java-native-interface

I am trying to write some android app making use of jni.

I have one Activity file which instantiates another class which makes call to jni function.

My cpp code is built fine and is put at location **libs/armeabi/libAppList.so**

My java file is like this.

```
package com.example.applist;

public class Backend {
    static {

        try {
            System.loadLibrary("AppList");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("Backend","caught exception" + e);
        }

    }        

    public native int createGroup() ;
}
```

and my makefile is like below

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

#Only compile source java files in this apk.

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := AppList

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_LIBS := libs/armeabi/libAppList.so
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

I am just instantiating this class from my main activity class for testing. (new Backend();)
However I receive a runtime error. Can someone explain what I am doing incorrect? I am just a new learner into this.

**# Edit:** 
I figured out how to write correct makefile.
Here it is:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
# Only compile source java files in this apk.
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES := libAppListBack
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libAppListBack
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := AppListNew
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PREBUILT_LIBS := libAppListBack:libs/armeabi/libAppListBack.so
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)

#include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

However C code I have to build through ndk and make a .so file.
If I uncomment the last line then my other makefile is executed but its not able to find out the .cpp file which is in same directory. I get an error No rule to make '/Backend.cpp'. Can anyone help with that?

It looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)  
include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_MODULE    := AppListBack
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Backend.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(JNI_H_INCLUDE)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
#LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Oops, it looks like an **[andorid-source](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-source/info)** question after all. Am I missing something?

Comment: So, you have `${AppListNew}/Android.mk` file for the Java app and `${AppListNew}/jni/Android.mk` file for `ibAppListBack.so`, and `${AppListNew}/jni/Backend.cpp` file also. But the second file looks for `/Backend.cpp` instead. Is that the situation?

Comment: @AlexCohn Hi, actually i left the idea of using jni in favor of using sockets as my C app needed some special permission that I was not able to work out using jni. I made a socket and spawned the C exe through java code and then established a socket and passed the data.

Answer (score 0):

Don't compile Java in makefile (Android.mk). You should build the Java part of your app with Ant. Even easier - use a GUI environment like the Google's ADT bundle. It can even run the ndk-build step for you.

Comment: I have some necessity to do it through makefile. It should be possible to do so as I am doing above, isnt it?

Comment: The supported way to build an Android application is to [use ant](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html). Yes, you can invoke `ant release` from make (use the APK file as target, and it's hard to list all the files this target depends on).